Oracle Apex - have Region occupy full width
I have a static region that needs to occupy the full width of the page.
<div style="background-color: blue;">

</div>

I'll need to add several other static regions that also need to be full width.
How to achieve this?

Hm. Regions, by default, are spread to the full width, aren't they? Shortly: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you describe it, possibly attach a screenshot which illustrates what you want?

What is in the region ? Depending on the component type it will or will not stretch

Thank you guys, found the answer. Page mode: normal, Template: Standard, Content Padding: remove padding.
